# AWS Lambda use Domain registered with other registrar

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

A Serverless Lambda function has been written.

I want to use a custom domain with the Lambda function to handle HTTPS requests. The domain is currently registered with a third-party registrar where I manage domains and would like to keep doing so.

The DNS server names for the domain have been updated to Route53 which has been handling requests for the domain; however, until now those were non-SSL.

I have generated a certificate using LetsEncrypt and imported it to AWS Certificate Manager; however, I have no way to associate the certificate with requests to the hosted zone.

**How can I activate the certificate with the Route53 hosted zone for Lambda requests without having to transfer the domain registrar?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda doesn't directly accept HTTP(S) Requests. For this you need to get yourself an API-Gateway and [configure your custom domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) with Certificate there.

Here's a list of supported event sources for Lambda from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html).

> - Amazon S3
> - Amazon DynamoDB
> - Amazon Kinesis Data Streams
> - Amazon Simple Notification Service
> - Amazon Simple Email Service
> - Amazon Simple Queue Service
> - Amazon Cognito
> - AWS CloudFormation
> - Amazon CloudWatch Logs
> - Amazon CloudWatch Events
> - AWS CodeCommit
> - Scheduled Events (powered by Amazon CloudWatch Events)
> - AWS Config
> - Amazon Alexa
> - Amazon Lex
> - Amazon API Gateway
> - AWS IoT Button
> - Amazon CloudFront
> - Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose
> - Other Event Sources: Invoking a Lambda Function On Demand

Comment: literally just got this working using API Gateway and was about to update here but you beat me to it :)